# Unable to mock s3 using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to mock the s3.listObjects.promise() and return a mock value for the same. However, I am not able to do the same. Here is my actual code followed by the Unit test.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
    console.log(`event is ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

    const Bucket = event.s3Usage.Bucket;
    const Prefix = event.s3Usage.Prefix || "";

    let s3BucketSize = 0;
    console.log(`Bucket name is ${Bucket} and Prefix is ${Prefix}`);
    
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    try {
        const data = await s3.listObjects({ Bucket, Prefix }).promise();
        console.log(`Data is ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
        if (data["Contents"].length > 1) {
            s3BucketSize = data["Contents"].filter(x => x.Size > 0).map(x => x.Size).reduce((x, y) => x + y);
            console.log(`Size of the folder is ${s3BucketSize} bytes.`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Size of the folder is 0 bytes.`);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error is ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        callback(err)
    }

    return s3BucketSize;
}
```

The following is my Unit test for the same:-

```
const handler = require("../index").handler;
const { S3 } = require('aws-sdk');

jest.mock('aws-sdk');

const mockOutput = {
    "IsTruncated": false,
    "Marker": "",
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "GodIsGreat.PNG",
            "LastModified": "2021-05-04T14:32:59.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"b45d6e6a40ab1c9ebf541093fe8959e6\"",
            "Size": 100,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Owner": {
                "ID": "98062a6ccbfb88d9b333868c14d5379ec23dab90210de79b2bfbd801e948ae0c"
            }
        },
        {
            "Key": "test/",
            "LastModified": "2021-03-02T08:09:37.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204\"",
            "Size": 50,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Owner": {
                "ID": "98062a6ccbfb88d9b3338"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Name": "xx",
    "Prefix": "",
    "MaxKeys": 1000,
    "CommonPrefixes": []
};

const s3ListObjectsPromise = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    promise: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockOutput)
});

S3.mockImplementation(() => ({
    listObjects: s3ListObjectsPromise
}));


const event = {
    s3Usage: {
        "Bucket": "xxx",
        "Prefix": ""
    }
};

describe("When the handler is invoked with an event", () => {
    // afterEach(jest.clearAllMocks);
    test("the correct response is returned", async () => {
        const res = await handler(event);
        console.log(`res value is ${res}`);
    });
});
```

As I run the test I see that the actual call to the S3 object is happening. How to avoid this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. It works for me.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thanks for your help. I specified the reason for failure as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine if both the files are under the same project. The reason why it failed is because my actual code and my test code are in different projects having different aws-sdk installed in them.

Under the hood they should work in the same aws-sdk and jest.

Thanks